# How do I choose a branch other than "default" for "master" when converting a repo from Mercurial to Git?

Tags: git, mercurial, branch

I need to convert an long-standing Mercurial repo to a Git repo (one-way, one-time conversion), and I'd like to pick a Mercurial branch other than `default` to be the `master` branch in the Git repo.

I've converted from Mercurial to Git on a smaller repo before, and after a few gotchas that were easy to Google and fix, it went well. In that case, it made sense to map `default` branch to `master`. (The only other branch mapping was "dev" to "dev".)

In this new case, the repository I have inherited uses the `default` branch for development, and then merges approved changes into a `stable` branch. So, when it comes over to Git, I'd like the Git `master` branch to reflect the `stable` Mercurial branch, and another branch to reflect the `default` Mercurial branch.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible.

Just convert your Mercurial repo to git, using whatever tools are convenient for you. If you end up with your final branches not to your liking, you can easily rename them. Use `git rename`.

For example, to rename branches "master" with "dev" (that is, swap the branches with each other):

```
git rename -m master master-old

git rename -m dev master

git rename -m master-old dev
```

See the `git-rename` man page for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I have never had the need to rename a branch before, and I didn't think it would be that easy.

Comment: Oh, one thing: you must have an alias or custom extension set up, because I had to use `git branch -m master master-old` and, _mutatis mutandis_ for renaming branches, because I don't have a `git rename` command available. Idea is right; I just had to change the command.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is (when using hg-git) creating a bookmark for the particular branch with the name master on the branch/revision that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution is to do a branch renaming/swapping in Mercurial *before* you convert the repository to Git, specifying exactly what branches you would like to have. E.g., for renaming `default` to `dev` and then `stable` to `default`, create a file called `branchmap.txt` with:

```
default dev
stable default
```

then run a conversion (the "convert" extension should be enabled in your hgrc) such as:

```
$ hg convert --branchmap branchmap.txt previousrepo newrepo
```

The only dangerous part of using "convert" to rename branches is that your resulting repository will be completely different: all SHA1s will be different. But as you are going to convert to Git afterwards, it does not really matter in this case.